# Limit number of decimal places in a Excel workbork (not specific cells)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook with multiple sheets on it and I want them all to limit the number of decimal places to 3 to prevent enormous numbers.

What I'm looking so far only applies to [specific cells](https://superuser.com/questions/102765/how-to-limit-the-number-of-decimal-places-in-an-excel-spreadsheet) and not a whole sheet.

If possible I would like to have a global rule for this (I don't prefer VBA answers but they're welcome as well).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: After the sheets already exist, I suspect it would be a bit of a mess.  There are some settings that generally work if you use them before you start.  Don't know how helpful these will be, but check out: https://www.addintools.com/documents/excel/where-specify-decimal-place.html and https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-rounding-precision-e5d707e3-07a8-4df2-810c-218c531eb06a.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks! I already know about those 2 settings but it can be helpful for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop the sheets in the document and set the numberformat for all cells with vba.

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    Cells.NumberFormat = "0.000"
Next ws
```

I don't think there is any global rules you can apply